# Using 'Facebook login' with C# SDK , plus ASPNET Membership Integration

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I followed the tutorial page on doing the basic Facebook authentication and login, but it seems to create a redirection loop.

The parent page sets up a  listener which, on authResponseChange, redirects to a handler.

The handler then gets the token and redirects back to the parent page

Which then sets up a listener, logs in, triggers authResponseChange and redirects to the handler. Etcetera...

Have I misunderstood something, or is this a bug or expected behaviour? I need to find a way to NOT have this happening.

Secondly, the documentation for 'Using Facebook & ASP.NET Membership for Authentication' is obviously not ready, but I would appreciate some pointers on how to do you would advise doing it.

**EDIT**: I presume that both of these issues would be fixed with the same solution, ie - getting the handler to redirect to a new page which creates a new ASPNET Membership user based on the facebook credentials - however I am unsure how to do this as the documentation for this section just says TODO. Any pointers? Would you need to just extend the Profile system to store the access token and facebook ID ? Or am I on totally the wrong track?

Answer (score 0):

On another demo [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20with%20an%20ASP.NET%20MVC%203%20Website%20%28With%20Javascript%20SDK%29&ANCHOR) some folks said it was a problem with ie9/chrome and cookies on localhost. Pointing to 127.0.0.1 and run it on iis it fixed the issue for me.